# Metadata for Lead Settings -> Record Type Setting

Tags: metadata, leads, assignment-rules

Is there any way to store the following option in metadata:

Setup -> Lead Settings -> The behavior used when applying assignment rules to manually created records. -> Record Type Setting
(options are: Keep the existing record type, Override the existing record type with the assignee's default record type)

It's not in settings/LeadConfig.settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having checked the Metadata Coverage Report and Metadata API, I don't see a way to store this configuration parameter. It is likely not supported.

Comment: Still the case in February 2023

Comment: Still the case in January 2024